# Nexus 7 Camera Problems (Can't select 720p)

Tags: camera, recording, video-recording, nexus-7

I have rooted, unlocked and modded my Nexus 7 with the 720p camera mod. If I go to `system/etc/media_profiles.xml`, it shows the 720p format.

The only problem is, that when I film with the default camera app, it films in 352x288. How do I select which video resolution I wish to use?

Screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwpdM.jpg)!

Circle button pressed - [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m86eL.jpg).